# DAX: Count times a measure exceeds a value

Tags: dax

Trying to count the # of Names on a Project where the Value > 1.0.
Project A Result = 1, Project B Result = 2 in this data:

**Project A**

- Name  Value
- Joe   1.5
- Bob   1.0
- Sue   0.8

**Project B**

- Name  Value
- Joe   1.5
- Bob   1.0
- Tom   1.8

Keep trying things with COUNTROWS and that works at the Name level, but not rolling up to Project level.

Comment: Unless you share how your tables are structured this question will be closed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to answer, because I don't completely understand your data or your question. Is Value the name of the measure? Or is Value a column in your table? (From what you posted, it looks more like a column in your table).
If you're trying to do something like filter out all the employees that worked more than 40 hours ***in total*** and you had a table of (EmployeeID, Date, HoursWorked), then you'd aggregate and then use filter.

```
FILTER('Employee',SUM('Working'[HoursWorked])>40)
```

returns a table of employees that worked more than 40 hours. To get a count of the employees (and not their names or whatever), you could use

```
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER('Employee',SUM('Working'[HoursWorked])>40)
  )
```

(because FILTER() returns a table, and then COUNTROWS() returns the number of rows in the table/table expression.

I find when I have a question, it's better to give some sample data, and then show my expected results, and how the logic works to get there. (So that someone can correct my code, and be sure what's being posted is correct.)

Comment: Understood and ty. In the table, I have the columns:
Project Title, Name, Hours.

In my example, Value is a measure that is correctly calculating a proprietary value mostly against hours. Probably not worth explaining the detail here, but my "Value" measure is correct. So what I want is to count at the Project level the number of Names / Employees where my measure Value is > 1.

Comment: Actually, I got it. Hope this helps someone else.

Measure = 
COUNTX(
    FILTER(Values(Table[Employee Name]),[ValueMeasure]>1),Table[Employee Name])